# How do i plot k-mean clustering from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, k-means

I am trying to cluster data from product sales of various companies. Note that I mapped any strings in my columns to numerical values so i could use k-means clustering. I have the following code where i am doing k-means on my data

```
FeaturesDf=FeaturesDf[['company_value','Date_value','product_value']]
# Convert DataFrame to matrix
mat = FeaturesDf.values
#Using sklearn
km = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=5)
km.fit(mat)
# Get cluster assignment labels
labels = km.labels_
# Format results as a DataFrame
results = pd.DataFrame(data=labels, columns=['cluster'], index=orderFeaturesDf.index)
```

how do i plot a k-means clustering plot of this? I tried

```
plt.scatter(results.index,results['cluster'], c='black')
plt.plot(results)
```

but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is the problem with the way you did it? You should specify your problem, otherwise this question is likely to be closed as opinion based (there are many ways of plotting data in python).

Answer (score 9):

Same thing as you did, but you can call `plot.scatter` on the DataFrame itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

n = 1000
d = pd.DataFrame({
        'x': np.random.randint(0,100,n),
        'y': np.random.randint(0,100,n),
    })

m = KMeans(5)
m.fit(d)

d['cl'] = m.labels_
d.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='cl', colormap='gist_rainbow')
```

Output:

[image]